# Pandas rename & reindex: ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

```
def Transformation_To_UpdateNex(df):
   s = 'TERM-ID,NAME,QUALIFIER,FACET1_ID,FACET2_ID,FACET3_ID,FACET4_ID,GROUP1_ID,GROUP2_ID,GROUP3_ID,GROUP4_ID,IS_VALID,IS_SELLABLE,IS_PRIMARY,IS_BRANCHABLE,HAS_RULES,FOR_SUGGESTION,IS_SAVED,S_NEG,SCORE,GOOGLE_SV,CPC,SINGULARTEXT,SING_PLU_VORGABE'
   df_Import = pd.DataFrame(columns = s.split(','))
   d = {'TERMID':'TERM-ID', 'NAMECHANGE':'NAME', 'TYP':'QUALIFIER'}
   df_Import = df.rename(columns = d).reindex(columns=df_Import.columns)

   df_Import.to_csv("Update.csv", sep=";", index = False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")


ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I am trying to take values from a filled Dataframe and transfer these values keeping the same structure to my new Dataframe (*empty one described first in the code*). 
Any ideas how to solve the value error?

Comment: When I run your code it doesn't throw any errors (though the output doesn't look like it's what I think you want...)

Answer (score 1):

So error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

means there are duplicated columns names.

I think problem is with `rename`, because it create duplicated columns:

```
s = 'TERM-ID,NAME,QUALIFIER,FACET1_ID,NAMECHANGE,TYP'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = s.split(','))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TERM-ID, NAME, QUALIFIER, FACET1_ID, NAMECHANGE, TYP]
Index: []
```

Here after rename get duplicated `NAME` and `QUALIFIER` columns, because original columns are `NAME` and `NAMECHANGE` and also `QUALIFIER` and `TYP` pairs:

```
d = {'TERMID':'TERM-ID', 'NAMECHANGE':'NAME', 'TYP':'QUALIFIER'}
df1 = df.rename(columns = d)
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TERM-ID, NAME, QUALIFIER, FACET1_ID, NAME, QUALIFIER]
Index: []
```

Possible solution is test, if exist column and filter dictionary:

```
d = {'TERMID':'TERM-ID', 'NAMECHANGE':'NAME', 'TYP':'QUALIFIER'}

d1 = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v not in df.columns}
print (d1)
{}

df1 = df.rename(columns = d1)
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TERM-ID, NAME, QUALIFIER, FACET1_ID, NAMECHANGE, TYP]
Index: []
```